# .htaccess redirect all subfolders to specific path

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

I have multiple sites (subdirectories). I want to redirect all URLs of the format `/(*)/login` to `/other/login`.

I have tried:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/login /other/login
#and 
^(.*)/login /other/login
```

I've also tried `Redirect`.

Additionally, I notice that some subfolders have their own `.htaccess` files also. Do I need to put the redirect rule in the subfolder's `.htaccess` file? There surely must be a more efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I notice some subfolder have their own `.htaccess` files also, do I need to put the redirect rule in the subfolder `.htaccess` files?

Any mod_rewrite directives in child `.htaccess` files will, by default, completely override the mod_rewrite directives in any parent `.htaccess` file, they are not *inherited*. However, you can change this behaviour. On Apache 2.2 this is quite limited as you would need to change the child `.htaccess` file anyway, so it would probably be easier to simply duplicate this directive in the child config. But on Apache 2.4.8+ you can do all this in the parent `.htaccess` file. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions InheritDownBefore

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/other
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/login$ /other/login [R=302,L]
```

The `InheritDownBefore` option results in the current mod_rewrite directives being applied *before* the mod_rewrite directives in any child configs.

The `RewriteCond` directive is required in order to prevent a redirect loop (if the `/other` subdirectory does not have its own `.htaccess` file containing mod_rewrite directives).

This is an external "redirect" (as stated in your question). The URL changes in the browser's address bar. You can possibly change this to an internal rewrite (as your current directive implies) by removing the `R` flag (although this may depend on your application).

---

If you simply want a "redirect" then you could probably use a mod_alias `RedirectMatch` directive instead of the above mod_rewrite directives. This runs separately to mod_rewrite, but note that any mod_rewrite directives (in child configs) are processed first. For example:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/(?!other)[^/]+/login$ /other/login
```

The `RedirectMatch` directive uses a regex, whereas `Redirect` (also mod_alias) uses simple prefix matching. So, you couldn't match this specific *pattern* using a simply `Redirect`.

The `(?!other)` part is a negative lookahead (zero-width assertion) that checks that the URL-path being matched does not start `other` - in order to avoid a redirect loop.

Note also that `RewriteRule` does not use the slash prefix on the URL-path, whereas, `RedirectMatch` does. And there is no need to capture the URL-path (ie. by enclosing the regex in parentheses) if this is not required.

Comment: this was close but I had to modify to create a RewriteCond to not match with /other/login and create a loop

Comment: @Rodrick Ah yes - I overlooked that! (If the the `/other` subdirectory contained a `.htaccess` file with mod_rewrite directives then that would have also avoided a redirect loop.) I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have try several variants (you can see marked lines, that doesn't works),
my `.htaccess`:

```
#AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^([^/]*)+^(.*)$ index.php?dir=$1&path=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

#FallbackResource index.php
```

It works with all urls: /, /index, /index.html, /main/main.html.

Then `echo var_dumps($_GET);` gives:

```
array(1) { ["path"]=> string(10) "index.html" }
```

Now all requests goes into `index.php`.